# Determine if the series $\frac{((\ln(n))^3}{n}$ is convergent or divergent.

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Determine if the series $\frac{((\ln(n))^3}{n}$ is convergent or divergent.

**What I Tried** :- If I were to use the comparison test would I end up with $(\ln(n))^3 > 1/n^2 > 0$. So
$\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent by $p$-test as $(p=2>1)$.
Therefore the original series is convergent by comparison test.

Can anyone help me understand If I am heading in the right direction?

Comment: Check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/562589 for MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference.

Comment: Use: $\ln n>1$ for $n >3$. The series is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not work.

The comparison test states that if $\sum b_{k}$ *converges* and $0\leq a_{n} \leq b_{n}$ for all natural numbers $n$ greater than some fixed natural number $N$, then $\sum a_{k}$ *converges*.

On the other hand if $\sum a_{k}$ *diverges* and $0\leq a_{m} \leq b_{m}$ for all natural numbers $m$ greater than some fixed natural number $M$, then $\sum b_{k}$ *diverges*.

**Hint**: What happens if you compare $\frac{(\ln n)^{3}}{n}$ with $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: How do we know the 1/n is what we want to compare the original to? Figuring out b_n is the most confusing part for me on direct comparisons.

Comment: $\frac{(\ln n)^{3}}{n}$ is essentially $\frac{\text{Something that gets larger}}{n}$, and we know that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. So it is natural to ask if "Something that gets larger" is greater than $1$ from some point onwards